# List in REST Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am having a REST service in which i am invoking a function which return a List.I want to send it in the response but i am getting issue.Can anyone explain me how can the collection can be deserialised in the REST response.I am using Jersey.one solution would be to create a POJO class with XMLRootElement etc.Is there other way to create a REST RESPONSE from List?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make separate response class inherited from the list:

```
public class MyResponse extends ArrayList<...> {
   ...
```

Or use in response raw array of objects instead of the list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please give a sample code for the same?

Comment: Thanks for the help.I was aware of this method.I was just thinking if there could be other method where we can directly set it in the response instead of creating another class.Anyways i will use this.